# UWP - How to duplicate PivotItem with his content

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, webview2

I want to create tabs with Pivot, I have WebView2 in the tab which is the important content. I wanted to create new PivotItem and duplicate the WebView2 already present on my first Tab.

Here is my codes:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Pivot x:Name="pivot" Margin="40,0,0,40">
        <PivotItem Header="Tab 1">
            <Grid>
                <controls:WebView2 x:Name="webView2" x:FieldModifier="public"
                       Source="https://example.com"
                       NavigationStarting="webView2_NavigationStarting" NavigationCompleted="webView2_NavigationCompleted" Margin="-12,0,-12,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

-

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="addButton" Icon="Add" Label="New Tab" Click="addButton_Click"/>
<AppBarButton x:Name="removeButton" Icon="Remove" Label="Remove Tab" Click="removeButton_Click"/>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pivotItem.Header = "New Tab" + null;
        pivotItem.Content = null; // temporary null before I got a solution
        pivot.Items.Add(pivotItem);
        pivotItem = null;
    }

    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pivot.Items.Remove(pivot.SelectedItem);
        // Close the software if there is no PivotItems
        if (pivot.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why you need to clone the webview2 control instead of creating a new one and navigating to the same URL? You could save the important data locally and use it in the new webview2 control.

Comment: I have some code for NavigationStarting on the base WebView2 I used and I want to avoid duplicated code in my project.

Comment: Why not put the code into a utility class so you don't need to write it many times? It will be very complicated to clone a control in UWP because there is no built-in clone method for UWP.

Comment: I think I'm going to doing this.